# Attribute Keyword with Index=true fails on search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am indexing a list of websites and Urls is one of the properties for Website (Name, Location being the others). I want to search a website using a url/s. I don't want to analyze this property and want to search on the full url (keyword). So my code looks like this.

```
[Keyword(index = true)]
public IEnumerable<string> Urls {get; set;}
```

Once index is created the mapping looks like the following,
"urls": {
   "type": "keyword"
}

However, when I search for a url, say "www.yahoo.com", no results are returned.
Two questions:

a) Why is it not returning the document? It is a simple keyword search hence should return the match.

b) Is doing the above same as indexing using the default analyzer? In my opinion keyword search without analyzing is 'explicit' and probably faster.

Thanks.

PS: My search code uses Nest (v5.0.0.0) as follows.

```
public SearchResult<Website> Search(string qry, int page, int pageSize)
{
   var result = client.Search<Website>(x => x.Query(q => q.MultiMatch(mp => mp.Query(qry).Fields(f => f.Fields(f1 => f1.Name, f2 => f2.Urls, f3 => f3.Locations)))).Size(pageSize));

   return new SearchResult<Website>
   {
      Results = result.Documents
   };
}
```

Comment: How are you searching, can you show the search request that you are doing? I suspect that you are using a full-text query that performs analysis on the query input

Comment: Search code added. I think you are correct. The low level query my search code resolves to, is probably using full-text. But will await your confirmation. Is there a way to see exactly what low level query was sent to ES?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query a field with `type=keyword` as full-text query i.e. match query, it uses a `search_analyzer` which defaults to the analyzer setting.

At index time, Elasticsearch will look for an analyzer in this order:

- The analyzer defined in the field mapping.
- An analyzer named default in the index settings.
- The standard analyzer.

At query time, there are a few more layers:

- The analyzer defined in a full-text query.
- The search_analyzer defined in the field mapping.
- The analyzer defined in the field mapping.
- An analyzer named default_search in the index settings.
- An analyzer named default in the index settings.
- The standard analyzer.

Assuming you do not have of the above defined, then your query input is being analyzed by the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which makes it split based on specific delimiters

FIX :

1. Update the field mapping for `[search_analyzer][2]` to [Keyword Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-keyword-analyzer.html)
2. Use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Comment: Thanks. Very useful info for someone like me who is starting out on ES.

Comment: I think @Redzon still wants to map as `keyword` type but perhaps add a normalizer to lowercase : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/normalizer.html. Then use a `term` query as you've suggested

Comment: @RussCam, yep, adding a normalizer to lowercase and using term query as rahuldoc suggested did the trick. Thank you guys.